# Checking for default value when using Linq, var and FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine I am doing this:

```
var player = players.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or indeed any complicated LINQ expression where the last function run is `FirstOrDefault`.

After executing it, `player` can `default()`. How do I check for this whilst keeping a `var` style type declaration? Is it even possible in c#?

1.

```
if (player == default(Player))
```

The explicit `Player` makes the `var player` feel useless. I might as well use `Player player = ...` instead of `var player ...`, and the entire question here is how to keep `var` around.

2.

```
if (player == default(typeof(player)))
```

is not compilable. I could do `typeof(Player)` but see above for how pointless that feels.

3.

```
if (player == null)
```

as `default(any reference type)` is `null`. But obviously this isn't correct if Player class is a `struct` type.

I'm aware that I could check the size of the array and THEN do `.First()` or even `.DefaultIfEmpty(something)`, but that makes `.FirstOrDefault()` pointless and in the `.DefaultIfEmpty` case requires you to know the class type, which doesn't obey the `var` limitation of that question.

Is there any way I can write this code using `var` that works fine for all types var could be standing in for?

Comment: Why is it so important in point 1 to "keep var around"?

Comment: It's important in all of the points :) I just wondered if it was possible to keep the type names out of this expression, and still check for default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T source)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(source, default(T));
    }
}
```

and then use:

```
var player = players.FirstOrDefault();
if (player.IsDefault())
{
    //
}
```

Comment: After asking the question, whilst washing up, I actually thought up something similar myself. Your version has the added 'benefit' of using EqualityComparer to avoid calling the sources .equals like mine would. Did you write this just for the answer or is it something you already had?

Answer (score 2):

Either `null` or `0` or `default(TheTypeGoesHere)`.

The only time when `var` lets you do something you can't do without it is with anonymous types, and since they are always reference types you can use `null` in that case.

Comment: Try to do it with structure or int list.

Comment: @Vlad try to do what with a structure or int list? For the structure we'd obviously use the third answer there and for an int list either the first or the third (mean the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a collection want to get the default value without having to specify the type you could do something like:

```
if(player == players.Take(0).SingleOrDefault())
```

or

```
if(player == players.SingleOrDefault(o => false))
```

Comment: Good idea :) Though I accepted the extension method idea as it offers more readability.